# Cambiar la conexion en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo 3 bases de datos la primera que es la principal que esta configurada en mi archivo .env, las otras dos son exactamente las mismas pero son de dos contratos diferentes, por lo tanto los modelos son los mismos y tambien los controladores, pero como puedo cambiar la conexion en el controlador dependiendo del contrato?
Actualmente la unica solucion que se me ocurrio fue crear dos modelos diferentes los cuales se conectan a una conexion diferente y dos controladores diferentes

Este seria mi Modelo de datosA

```
class DatosA extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'DB_1';
    public $table = "datos";
    protected $fillable = ['id',, 'nombre', 'apellido', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

Y este para datosB

```
class DatosB extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'DB_2';
    public $table = "datos";
    protected $fillable = ['id',, 'nombre', 'apellido', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

Este es el controlador del Modelo de DatosA

```
class DatosAController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
    {
       return DatosA::all();
    }
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $datos = DatosA::create($request->all());
        return $this->succesResponse($datos);
    }
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $datos = DatosA::findOrFail($id);
        $datos->update($request->all());
        return $this->succesResponse($datos);
    } }
```

Este es controlador de Datos de B

```
class DatosBController extends Controller
{
 public function index()
    {
       return DatosB::all();
    }
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $datos = DatosB::create($request->all());
        return $this->succesResponse($datos);
    }
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $datos = DatosB::findOrFail($id);
        $datos->update($request->all());
        return $this->succesResponse($datos);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es que debes definir una conexión dinámica en el array de conexiones del archivo de configuración: "config\database.php", ejemplo:

```php
'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
        'mysql_dinamica' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
]
```

Luego crear un Middleware: app\Http\Middleware que gestione el cambio de la conexión dependiente de cualquier criterio, ejemplo: el dominio, un parámetro en el header, etc...

ejemplo:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;


class CheckDataBase
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $namedb = Request::header('namedb'); // Este es el parámetro a validar
        if(!empty($namedb)){
            \Config::set('database.connections.mysql_dinamica.database',$namedb); // Asigno la DB que voy a usar
            DB::connection('mysql_dinamica'); //Asigno la nueva conexión al sistema. 
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

De esa forma puedes manejar varias conexión al dependiendo de un criterio en cuanto al modelo solo debes asignar la conexión dinámica.

```php
 protected $connection = "mysql_dinamica";
```

Comment: Sí, esto funciona de maravilla.